# If $g: R \rightarrow R$ and $g(x)=9-x^{2}$ find $g^{-1}([8,10])$

Tags: general-topology

Okay so I've trying to draw the graph so I can get the image but I'm stuck. When I solve

$8=9-x^{2}$ I get x=+/- 1

But when I got to solve for 10 you obviously get $\sqrt(-1)$ which doesn't work. So I am having trouble finding the projection of $g^{-1}$ onto the x-axis. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By definition $x \in g^{-1}([8,10])$ if and only if

$$ g(x) \in [8, 10 ] \Leftrightarrow  8 \leq 9-x^2 \leq 10$$

Answer (score 0):

Finding $g^{-1}([8,10])$ is the same as solving the inequality $8 \leq 9 - x^2 \leq 10$.  First of all, we can subtract $8$ from all sides, so we get $0 \leq 1- x^2 \leq 2$.  So we need to find the set of all $x$ such that $0 \leq 1- x^2$ and $1- x^2 \leq 2$.  So ask yourself three questions:

1. Under what conditions is $0 \leq 1- x^2$?
2. Under what conditions is $1- x^2 \leq 2$?
3. Under what conditions are both true?